# Como imprimir apenas uma vez o nome repetido?

Tags: c

Para um ou dois nomes repetidos, ele funciona até bem, mas se eu faço com que todos sejam iguais ele repete umas dez vezes. Eu já tentei usar flag, mas não consigo perceber o raciocínio.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* 
Lucas Correia, 2018

 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char nomes[5][50];
    int i=0, j=0, flag = 0;

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Informe o nome:");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", nomes[i]);
    }


    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = i+ 1; j < 5; j++){
            if(stricmp(nomes[i], nomes[j])==0){
                printf("\nRepetead: %s", nomes[i]);
                flag = 1;
                if(!flag){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pode criar outra variavel que armazena nomes repetidos, depois so insira lá caso nao exista, depois é so imprimir

Comment: Defina "repetido". Se existir dois iguais na lista toda já é repetido? Ou só quando aparece pela segunda vez é repetido?

Comment: Se existir dois iguais na lista já é repetido. Estou tentando entender corretamente comparação de strings para usar numa validação de nomes. Por exemplo, se já houver um nome na lista, ele pede para o usuário digitar o nome de novo.

Comment: @LucasCorreia Pode usar a minha implementação, so que em vez de usar `nomes_repetidos` pede outra vez um nome diferente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa para solucionar esse problema é criar uma nova variavel `nomes_repetidos` em que armazena os nomes repetidos, **caso não exista ainda**, para isso é preciso uma função que procura no vetor se existe ou não.

---

Usando memoria estática como tem vindo a utilizar:

```
/** 1 caso encontre | -1 caso não encontre **/
int procura(char nome[][50], int n, char nome_rep[50])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(nome[i],nome_rep))
            return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Neste excerto de codigo abaixo o que faz é:

1. Ver se é uma palavra repetida
2. Caso seja repetida e não exista em `nomes_repetidos` adiciona
3. Aumenta o tamanho de `nomes_repetidos`

---

```
 if(strcmp(nomes[i], nomes[j])==0)  /** 1. **/
    {
       if(procura(nomes_repetidos, tamanho, nomes[i])==-1)  /** 2. **/
       {
           strcpy(nomes_repetidos[tamanho], nomes[i]); /** 2. **/
           tamanho++;  /** 3. **/
       }
    }
```

---

Depois disso, basta apenas imprimir os seus dados normalmente:

```
for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++ )
        printf("\nRepetead: %s", nomes_repetidos[i]);
```

**[CÓDIGO COMPLETO NO IDEONE](https://ideone.com/w7cMh5)**